# Getting the type of a value and assigning it to a property

Tags: typescript

Typing data in typescript I came across a problem, Generic assignment.

when we create a variable, before the value assignment, its type is any, but after it is initialized, it assumes the type of the value that was passed.

Example:

```js
const foo: string = ''; //string

let bar = foo;       //string

interface IFilter{
    db: ////assumes the type of the past value;
    fields: keyof IFilter["db"];
}

const db: WebSQL = WebSQL;

const filter: IFilter = {
    db: db,
    fields: ["id", "index"]
}
```

automatically bar assumes the same type of foo.

is it possible to do something similar when assigning types?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript has the `as` keyword. So, if I'm understanding your question correctly, you can do something like this:

[image]

I do this often when I'm working in React too (with TS) because I often need to initialize a `const` as `null` but in the future know it will hold an `XYZ` type later.

Comment: I believe it would be something like this:
``` 
interface IFilter{
  db: //assumes the type of the past value;
  fields: keyof IFilter["db"];
}
const db: WebSQL = WebSQL;
    const filter = {
        db,
        fields: ["index", "label"]
    }
```

but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Yes, that totally works too!  For example, this is valid TS code: `const abc: string = 'xyz'`

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Here is the solution:

```
interface WebSQL {
  woof: string[];
  bark: number;
}
```

Then you can:

```
interface IFilter<T> {
  db: T;
  fields: (keyof IFilter<T>["db"])[];
}
```

Then you can:

```
const filter: IFilter<WebSQL> = {
  db: { bark: 1, woof: [] },
  fields: ["bark"],
};
```

[image]

[image]